# Submit Form from angularjs after validate with Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, submit

I have html form and angular controller.
In controller I have one function to check user data on the server.
and I call this function in button at html by using

```
ng-click
```

after success , I want submit form from controller.

How can I access `form.submit` from angular controller ?

Thank !!!

Comment: use ng-submit look this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive on your form. From there you may return true/false after your validation.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function(user) {
    var isvalid = true;

    // Add your code 
    // for server validation here

    if (isvalid) {
        return true;
    }
    return false; //failed
  }
});
```

**Html**

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submit(user)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose on `ng-click` you call,

```
validate();
```

In this function u can do validation and form submission action as follows( my syntax may not be correct....but I'am just trying to convey my idea)

```
$scope.vaidate = function(input) { 

    //Add your validation code here, it includes api call etc.

    // If validation succeeds, run code for submitting the form. 
    if() // add validation success condition
    {
         //run code for submitting the form.
    }
    else
    {
         // Add code to show error message within the html form.
    }

}
```

I think you can run submit action within the if condition.

Comment: thank Jacky, this is what I did, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using jquery to select form with method submit

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

It work fine for me !!!